# Is there any validation on Integer field to check exact value for rest api ? @Min and @Max is not working

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest

Like

```
@Min or @Max is not working
```

I want exact value to be match.

Comment: if you have an exact value, why should you get it as parameter?? just use a variable with that value(?)

Comment: I have to design a rest api where user needs to put interest rate and it should be fixed value and I am using jpa.

Comment: Maybe you could use a regex, something like `@Pattern(regexp="^50$")` to match value `50`. Not tested.

Comment: Another example: We have a conditional validation. If A, the value is required to be between 1 and 51, if B, the value must be 0. This works fine with `@Min` and `@Max` with different groups for A, but not for B. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own annotation that validates it.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = ConstantInterestRateValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ConstantInterestRate {
    String message() default "Incorrect interest rate";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

```
public class ConstantInterestRateValidator implements 
  ConstraintValidator<ConstantInterestRate, Integer> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConstantInterestRate constantInterestRate) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String field,
      ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        return contactField != null && field == 50;
    }

}
```

use it like any other validation annotation

```
class Foo {
   @ConstantInterestRate
   Integer bar;
}
```

Have fun with it, you could also add parameter to your custom annotation and avoid hardcoding values.